# How to merge the videos using AVMutableComposition in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, ios6

i have used the following way but videos didn't merge and in the output the last video added to AVMutableCompositionTrack gets stored in Library.

```
NSArray *arrVideoUrl=[objApp.dictSelectedVideos allKeys];
AVURLAsset *video1=[[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:[arrVideoUrl objectAtIndex:0] options:nil];
AVURLAsset *video2=[[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:[arrVideoUrl objectAtIndex:1] options:nil];
AVURLAsset *audioAsset=[[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:songUrl options:nil];

AVMutableComposition *mixcomposition=[AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *track1=[mixcomposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[track1 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, video1.duration) ofTrack:[[video1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                 atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];


AVMutableCompositionTrack *track2=[mixcomposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

[track2 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, video2.duration) ofTrack:[[video2 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                 atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
```

Can anyone please help me out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now You have `AVMutableComposition`s for both tracks, you need to create --
- `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` for both of them.

- Create `AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction` for your merged track whose object will be
  having `instructions` in an Array consisting of `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` 
  for first and second track.
- Create `AVMutableVideoComposition` for Merged track object and provide above
  `AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction`.

This approach is from a very good Tutorial from [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios) link.

Comment: Well thanx for this ..it worked !!! but I am getting the problem in orientation ...the video orientation is set to landscape,which is default for AVAsset . I used the tutorial given by your link but the orientation problem is coming. Can you help me to get out of this ?

Comment: glad to help...for Orientation if nothings working then you could try 'transform' properties on AVPlayerLayer, by doing transformation (CGAfflineTransform) according to device orientations.

Comment: Thanks for the code! Oh wait, you didn't leave any... -1

Comment: cause directions are enough for some developers.